# Attempting to add my SSH key to the ssh-agent but getting 'no such file or directory.'

Tags: git, ssh

Below are my steps to create and attempt to add an SSH key but I'm rather unsure where I am going wrong, any help is greatly appreciated! (I'm new to this, sorry)

Following online instructions, I first generated a new shh-key using the following code:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "[my email]"
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Akiper/.ssh/id_ed25519):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in
Your public key has been saved in  .pub
```

etc.

I then made sure that the ssh-agent was running in the background and attempted to add my generated shh-key to the shh-agent but i got the following error:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent -s`
Agent pid 304

$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
/c/Users/Akiper/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file to directory
```

As you can see in the third line of code, the key was saved in the following file:

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users/Akiper/.ssh/id_ed25519):
```

and as you can imagine, I am rather confused as to why the code says that it cannot find the key in such, or I may be interpreting the code wrong. Again, any help and advice are appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: In cmd window: `dir c:\Users\Akiper\.ssh`; in git-bash: `ls ~/.ssh/` — is the file there? If not, what files are there?

Comment: Look at the last two lines of the output from `ssh-keygen`. Something fishy is going on.

Comment: Did you accidentally type a space before hitting Enter for the file name? It doesn't look like the default was used.

Comment: @phd when I type that in, I get the following 

```ls: cannot access `/c/Users/Akiper/.ssh/`: No such file or directory```

Comment: This version of `ssh-keygen` appears to have a bug; it should have either created the directory `/c/Users/Akiper/.ssh/` or reported an error, rather than silently doing ... whatever it is that it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you dont have any premade ssh keys in ~/.ssh/ directory
then try this out ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email"
follow the next steps as usual
ed25519 is 2048bits for rsa key whereas the above one is 4096 bits .

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I checked if I had any premade ssh keys and it seems like something happened in my code and the key was never saved even though everything looked in order? Maybe I just interpreted it wrong. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

Just like @iceweasel said, check if ~/.ssh/ directory is empty or not, delete any pre-existing keys. Then enter:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "email"
```

Then you will see an output such as:

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa):
                                                 leave this empty ^
Enter passphrase: 
     leave this empty ^
Enter same passphrase again:
             leave this empty ^
Your identification has been saved in /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa 
Your public key has been saved in /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Afterwards, type `cd ~/.ssh` into the terminal and check if `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` are available.
Then type `cat id_rsa.pub` and copy the key. Add that key in GitHub's SSH key if you want: You'll find the guide [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).
To set up the git-agent, run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` into the terminal.
Followed by `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

After completing all these steps, you're ready to commit changes and push your work to the remote repo.

Comment: thank you, you saved a new developer's day!